# What is the reason behind controllers is declared as a string in routes for Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, syntax, routes, controller

I am new to Laravel and something I have not understood is why the routes can be declared as a string. I think there is a good reason behind it just I don´t get it. Could someone explain it?

The two ways I found to declare a route using a controller in Laravel.

First:  `Route::get('hello', 'UserController@index');`

Second: `Route::get('hello1', [UserController::class, 'index']);`

However why should it be possible to make the function static and call it like this instead (I tried but did not work):

`Route::get('hello2', UserController::index());`

I think the last one should make it easier to autocomplete in IDE (the second works in my IDE, but still feels over complicated). So what is the reason for the string syntax? Once I again I am new to Laravel so understad its something I miss.

Comment: In your suggested alternative, you're actually calling the function at runtime and passing the **result** to the router. Instead, Laravel (and any other framework) requires a **reference** to the function, so that it can be called later, when the route is actually accessed in a browser. The closest way PHP has to doing this natively is the second example in your question - a [callable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php). There are several formats available for this, but a common one is an array containing a class name and a method name.

Comment: How exactly would `Controller::index()` work here? This would execute the method and return its value which means every route would execute. You pass the class and the method and it is accessed using Reflection later down the line. What stops you studying the source-code and finding out for yourself, its open-source is it not

Comment: Laravel (or PHP for that matter) does support using functions for the action, however, as pointed out previously, you don't want those functions to execute unless that specific route matches. One way to do that is to wrap it in an [anonymous function](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#basic-routing) such as `function () {return 'Hello World';}`. Since that is more verbose, and since there's a common pattern of class+method in a one-to-one relationship, the string pattern is often used.

Comment: I found now when using Route::apiResource(...), then the first way was easier Route::apiResource('users', 'UserController');. I didn´t manage to get the second way to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controller cant just call the method because it will make things more difficult to change later. When the controller gets to connected to the methods details, it will be tough to keep the code in good shape.

Better the controller should pass the methods reference as a parameter. This way the controller can use the method without getting tangled up in its specifics. Its a better way because it makes the code more flexible and easier to work on.

This is called "dependency injection" and its common to do in frameowrks. Its better to inject dependencies into a component than to have it create them directly. That way the component will be easier to test and maintain.

Passing a methods reference as a parameter is better than calling it directly. It helps to keep the controller from getting tied to the methods details. Making the code more adaptable and maintainable.